# Is SqlConnection.Close() need inside a Using statement?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I'm using this code:

```cs
public void InsertMember(Member member)
{
    string INSERT = "INSERT INTO Members (Name, Surname, EntryDate) VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @EntryDate)";

    using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(INSERT, sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = member.Name;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = member.Surname;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@EntryDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = member.EntryDate;

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

It's not showing any errors or problems at all. Is it wrong if I don't add `sqlConnection.Close();` before disposing of it? If yes, why?

Comment: The using statement will `Dispose` the connection even in case of an exception, so you don't really need a `Close` call there

Answer (score 61):

There is no need to `Close` (or `Dispose`) here; the `using` block will take care of that for you.

As stated from [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close):

> The following example creates a [SqlConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), opens it, [and] displays some of its properties. The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block.
>
> ```
> private static void OpenSqlConnection(string connectionString) 
> {
>     using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
>     {
>         connection.Open();
>         Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
>         Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
>     } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Is it OK if the code has a connection.Close(); just before your second last curly brace '}'? Will this throw an exception when the using block tries to close a connection that is already closed by code?

Answer (score 11):

According to the [Microsoft Learn documentation for the `Close` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close):

> you must explicitly close the connection by calling **Close** or **Dispose**. **Close** and **Dispose** are functionally equivalent.

Therefore, calling `Dispose` (implicitly so, even, using `using`) will cover your bases, as it were.

It's worth noting, too, I think,though not specific to your case, that `Close` will always effectively be called when the thing is wrapped in a `using` statement - which might *not* be the case should it be omitted and an exception occur without the proper `try`/`catch`/`finally` handling.

Comment: In the example it states: The following example creates a SqlConnection, opens it, displays some of its properties. The connection is automatically closed at the end of the using block.

Comment: @DarrenDavies Precisely. It's more explicit on the details even further up than that.

Answer (score 11):

The `using` statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is **translated by the compiler**. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

So ultimately your code line

```
using (sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString_WORK))
```

will be converted into a normal `try finally` block by compiler calling `IDisposable` object in the finally.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it wrong if I don't add sqlConnection.Close(); before disposing it

No, it is not as long as you are using your connection within `Using`.  When you will leave the using scope, `Dispose` will be called for sql connection. which will *close the existing connection* and free-up all the resources as well.

Answer (score 4):

The using statement is a try finally block and in your case the final block would have a `connection.Dispose()` call. So you don't really need a independent `connection.Close()` statement there.

The advantage is that this ensures the disposal even in case of an exception since the finally block will always run.

```
try
{
sqlConnection.Open();
// ....
}
finally
{
if(sqlConnection != null)
      sqlConnection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I think this is incorrect. The whole point of using is it should handle dispose in all cases.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/270939/c-using-then-exception-open-database

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not wrong. The sqlConnection will close the connection after it will pass **using** block and call Dispose method. SqlConnection.Dispose() equal to SqlConnection.Close() method.

From MSDN: *If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent.*

Answer (score 3):

You are using a `Using` which will `Dispose()` the object for you.

If you take the connection outside of the `Using` statement, then yes - you would need to close the connection when finished.